# In Scala 3, is it possible to summon implicits based on refined type?

Tags: scala, generics, implicit, scala-3

Considering the following example:

```scala
    {
      trait Gen {
        type S
        type Ext
      }
      type GenAux[_S] = Gen { type S = _S }

      trait Gen_Fallback1 {
        given [_S]: GenAux[_S] = new Gen {
          final override type S = _S
          final override type Ext = _S
        }
      }

      trait Gen_Fallback0 extends Gen_Fallback1 {
        given GenAux[Int] = new Gen {
          final override type S = Int
          final override type Ext = Long
        }
      }

      object Gen extends Gen_Fallback0 {
        given GenAux[Float] = new Gen {
          final override type S = Float
          final override type Ext = Double
        }
      }

      val gen = summon[GenAux[Int]]
      summon[gen.Ext =:= Long]
    }
```

The compiler (Scala3.3.0) will give the following the error:

```
summon[gen.Ext =:= Long]
      ^
Cannot prove that gen.Ext =:= Long.
```

The interesting part is that if `GenAux` is not a type alias, but an actual generic trait, the compilation will be successful. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the old trick with `Aux` pattern to express some sort of implication: "I have 2 parameters, but if one of them is X, then the other should by Y".

Thing is, from experience: is works the best if:

- the types used to "get a match" are normal type parameters - not path-dependent types!
- the types that should "be implied" should appear as path-dependent types
- then `Aux` ca be used to have both groups expressed as type parameters for our convenience

Once we rewrite your code this way it works:

```
trait Gen[S] {
  type Ext
}
object Gen extends Gen_Fallback0 {
  type Aux[S, _Ext] = Gen[S] { type Ext = _Ext }
}
trait Gen_Fallback0 extends Gen_Fallback1 { this: Gen.type =>
  given Gen.Aux[Int, Long] = new Gen[Int] {
    final override type Ext = Long
  }
}
trait Gen_Fallback1 { this: Gen.type =>
  given [S]: Gen.Aux[S, S] = new Gen[S] {
    final override type Ext = S
  }
}

val gen = summon[Gen[Int]]
summon[gen.Ext =:= Long]
```

(see: [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Vx5ch2WBTiatup13RzEd7Q)).

You can think that the way it works is that is looks for implicit which would return `Gen[Int]`. There is such implicit - one returning `Gen.Aux[Int, Long]` or `Gen[Int] { type Ext = Long }`. This type gets assigned to `gen` value, and compiler knows the exact type of `gen.Ext`.

In your code compiler looked for `GenAux[Int]` and got... `GenAux[Int]`. Which didn't reflect `type Ext` anywhere in the type signature. Perhaps when you replaced type alias with a generic you accidentally created a refined type which preserved the type information on `Ext`. Meanwhile when you used alias, you had `GenAux[Int]` there, which might have "upcasted" from `Gen { type S = Int; type Ext = Long }` to `Gen { type S = Int }`.